# How to check if a property value exists within a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, model-view-controller, types, indexof

I have an array of typed objects that is passed into my view from a controller. The requirement is to check if a string value matches any of the `AdminEmailAddress` string type objects within that array.

What I have tried is creating an `if condition` to check if the string `currentUserEmail` matches any of the admin emails within that list, using `indexOf`.

But the script breaks on the if condition:

```
 if (adminUserList.AdminEmailAddress.indexOf(currentUserEmail) > -1)
```

I also put an alert on the `currentUserEmail` string and the `adminUserList` array which are both populated with data.

The contents of the adminUserList during runtime is as follows for reference:

```
var adminUserList = [{"AdminID":1,"AdminDisplayName":"brianb","AdminEmailAddress":"brian@test.com"},{"AdminID":2,"AdminDisplayName":"wendy","AdminEmailAddress":"wendy@test.com"}];
```

**Question:**

How can you check if a string matches a property value within an array?

**Code:**

List type containing the AdminEmailAddress property -

```
List type public class AdminUsers
{
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public string AdminDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string AdminEmailAddress { get; set; }

}
```

List passed in from Controller to View:

```
List<AdminUsers> adminList = sqlConnection.GetAdminUsers();
ViewBag.AdminUserList = adminList;
```

Script that contains the `if condition`:

```
<script>

    var currentUserEmail = '@ViewBag.CurrUserEmail';
    var adminUserList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.AdminUserList));


    $(document).ready(function () {

        var historyTable = $('#table').DataTable({
            "order": [[6, "desc"]]
        });


        if (adminUserList.AdminEmailAddress.indexOf(currentUserEmail) > -1)
        {
            historyTable.columns([9]).visible(false);
        }



    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use following function:**

```
function checkEmailExists(currentUserEmail){

        var match = false;
        for(var i=0;i<adminUserList.length;i++){
            if(adminUserList[i]["AdminEmailAddress"].indexOf(currentUserEmail) > -1){
                match = true;
                break;
            }

        }

        return match;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following situation:

```
var adminUserList = [{"AdminID":1,"AdminDisplayName":"brianb","AdminEmailAddress":"brian@test.com"},{"AdminID":2,"AdminDisplayName":"wendy","AdminEmailAddress":"wendy@test.com"}];
var currentUserEmail = 'wendy@test.com';
```

Then you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find elements:

```
var matchArray = adminUserList.filter(function(element){
  return element.AdminEmailAddress === currentUserEmail;
})
alert(matchArray.length > 0);
```

This way you also have access to the actual results:

```
if(matchArray.length > 0) {
    alert(matchArray[0].AdminDisplayName)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the find function to [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the an element of the array:

```
var adminUserList = [{"AdminID":1,"AdminDisplayName":"brianb","AdminEmailAddress":"brian@test.com"},{"AdminID":2,"AdminDisplayName":"wendy","AdminEmailAddress":"wendy@test.com"}];

var mailToCheck = 'wendy@test.com'

var adminFound =  adminUserList.find(function(admin){ return admin.AdminEmailAddres === mailToCheck});
```

If the user is found the user will be returned, otherwise the adminFound will be `undefined`.

But why do that in the front-end ?
User data available in the browser, I do not think is a good practice.
I suggest that you do that in your backend and return a true/false response.